# Python 2.6: argument 1 must be string or pinned buffer, not bytearray for bytearray of UTF-8 string

Tags: file, unicode, utf-8, arrays, python-2.6

In Python 2.6.8 I get the following error when writing a unicode string:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    f.write(bytearray(u, 'utf_8'))
TypeError: argument 1 must be string or pinned buffer, not bytearray
```

When running the code in Python 2.7.8 everything works fine, the string is printed and written properly.

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

u = u"Möwe"

print u

with open("testout", "w") as f:
    f.write(bytearray(u, 'utf_8'))
```

The same behaviour occures for strings containing 4-byte UTF-8 chars.

Python 2.6 binary details:

```
$ python26 -v -c 'exit' 2>&1 | grep -A 1 '^Python'
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Nov  7 2012, 14:47:45) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)] on linux2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is opened in ascii mode per default, the unicode bytes can't be written since they contain non-ascii chars. You have to open the file in binary mode:

```
with open("testout", "wb") as f:
    f.write(bytearray(u, 'utf_8'))
```

[Python 2.6 docs on `open()`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/functions.html#open)